# Install SharePoint Powershell addin locally to use against Office365

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell

What do I need to install on my machine so that I can run Powershell scripts against our Office365 SharePoint farm?  I want to be able to spider for our Sites and then the folder tree in each.

Answer (score 1):

You need windows Powershell & .net Framework & Office 365 Sign-in Assistant.

[Install and Configure the Office 365 PowerShell Cmdlets](https://littletalk.wordpress.com/2013/09/23/install-and-configure-the-office-365-powershell-cmdlets/)

Also check this anwser: http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/148/t/21214.aspx